# How to add self signed certificate in kubernetes elastic search deployment using Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I am using https://www.elastic.co/blog/shipping-kubernetes-logs-to-elasticsearch-with-filebeat to ship kube logs to elastic search. I have self-signed elastic search host. How can I give certificate information to filebeat in kubernetes?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? For example, can you `curl` successfully from within the `filebeat` container (with the appreciation you might not have `curl` installed, but it's an invaluable debugging tool for that kind of thing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I solved this problem by adding self-signed certificate in filebeat daemonset. Anyone who wants to add can do it by following steps. Mount path depends on OS in which your container is running, I am assuming ubuntu:

1. Create secret with following code :

   ```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: self-signed-certificate-secret
    data:
      ca-certificates.crt: <base 64 encoded string of certificate>
   ```
2. Then edit filebeat-kubernets.yaml file. In daemonset section add the following line:

   ```
   volumeMounts:
   - name: cert
     mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
   ```
3. In volumes section add information related to volume mount cert:

   ```
   volumes:
   - name: cert
     secret:
     secretName: self-signed-certificate-secret
     defaultMode: 0400
   ```

Comment: Happy it worked for you. If we are mounting volume can't we directly copy the cert to /etc/ssl/certs path ? Do I still need to follow step 1 &3.